# Suppress the message (LSP :: not indexed)

Tags: lsp-mode, ccls

I couldn't find an option to suppress this message on unindexed files.

In my repo I have C++ files that I dont want to index and this message keeps showing up when moving the cursor between code lines.

Is there a way to suppress it? Or view it once when visiting an unindexed file instead of continuously?

Comment: Try first to update your ```lsp-mode``` and ```lsp-ui``` packages to the latest version - released a couple a weeks ago (for me removed an annoying message). Maybe will work also for you.

Comment: I actually already have latest versions.

Comment: I have experienced the same error message when using ```lsp + ccls```- I use a Mac - and moved to ```eglot + clangd``` for a while, and then recently moved to ```lsp + clangd```, and I do not have any problem. I think maybe worth to ask at https://github.com/MaskRay/emacs-ccls/issues.

Comment: I don't have problem with the message. My problem is with the message keep showing up whenever I move the cursor!